# Databinding an Object Type to ListViewColumns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Good day,

I am trying to Bind data to my ListView Columns and I am having trouble.

```
public partial class ListViewItem
{
    public object Tag
    {
        get { return _tag; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _tag) return;
            _tag = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

This Tag Property is set to be a `List<ActionObject>` For simplicity sake, i'll just post the class with one variable in it.

```
public class ActionObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _command;
    public string Command
    {
        get { return _command; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _command) return;
            _command = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the XAML Code

```
<ListView x:Name="ActionLV" ItemsSource="{Binding ActionData.ListViewCollection}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Command" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Tag.Command, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

In the image below you can see that ListViewCollection is being populated, but its not updating.

```
    private ObservableCollection<ListViewItem> _listViewCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<ListViewItem> ListViewCollection
    {
        get { return _listViewCollection; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _listViewCollection) return;
            _listViewCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

[image: Proof that the collection is being populated]

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but I noticed you didn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your ListViewItem class, even though it you created it to be observable.

Comment: Replace this `{Binding Tag.Command` with `{Binding Tag[0].Command`, and see if it shows up something.

Comment: Unfortunatly yes I already have the INotifyPropertyChanged on it and Tag[0].Command does not work :(